# How can I use regex to get numbers and Chinese?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

```
import re
text = "我去臺中10天9夜，我去臺中10天九夜"
```

I have text like this.

```
res = re.findall(regex, text)
print(res)
# ["10天9夜", "10天九夜"]
```

I want to use regex to get the res like this.
How can I get this res?

If I want to math `["10天9夜"]`, I can use `re.findall("\d+\天\d+\夜", text)`, but it only match one.

Comment: Does it mean you want to match one or more consecutive sequences of digits and then letters?

Comment: If I want to math ["10天9夜"], I can use re.findall("\d+\天\d+\夜", text), but it only match one.
I want to know how to write the regex then I can math "10天9夜" and "10天九夜".

Comment: I updated your question with the attempt and posted an answer based on your idea of matching digits and letters mixed with the repetition approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
re.findall(r'(?:\d+[^\W\d_]+)+', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v7KqN9/1), this pattern matches one or more consecutive sequences of digits and then letters.

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a "container", a non-capturing group

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more letters
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot, I learned a lesson